# Highcharts push max values past preset

Tags: highcharts, max, push

I am setting up a chart that has the min and max values set. Every 10 seconds the graph is updated with new data and the series is pushed over. All is working fine except on some rare occasions, the data pushes past my max. I have been trying to fine like a minHeight type thing, that sets the max, but in the event the data goes above that max, it pushes it out until that data is gone again?

My values are set to min 0, and max 7000, I have it set this way so at a glance you can see that the line moving along 600 is well within specs, and at about 6000 its way over where it should be. But since it only shows 1 hour, there has been some times when the bar disappears and it look s like it isn't loading.

Here is a sample of what my data would look like in the event the data does go past the max - http://jsfiddle.net/J2f47/

```
 $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: -5,
                max: 40,
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 28.2, 36.5, 41.2, 46.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Thank You
Kirt

Comment: Well, your jsFiddle demo doesn't suit the description of the problem? You talk about 600, 6000, 7000 etc, but in example values are really different. Maybe you need [ceiling](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.ceiling) option?

Comment: OK so my example may not have matched my circumstances. Here is my revised version that matches what I am looking at better. http://jsfiddle.net/J2f47/1/. So the first series, the lower almost straight line is what I get most of the day, and the Min and Max would be 0->7000, this gives me a quick, at a glance idea, that everything is OK. The second series shows it spike, it doesn't always, but when it does, I would like the max to adjust to follow... If I set the max to 10000 it makes it harder to notices the small fluctuations, So I only want it to rise when it peaks over 7000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would suggest to set `max` after checking if series contains peaks or not, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/J2f47/2/

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

var data1 = [600, 621, 628, 656, 612, 676, 641, 648, 708, 665, 659, 640],
    data2 = [672, 689, 4820, 4864, 4871, 4880, 4869, 7786, 7692, 7744, 4770, 5769],
    max = data2.max();
```

Then in options:

```
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: max > 7000 ? max : 7000,
            tickInterval: 1000,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
        },
```

If you have live updates, then just check if new point is higher than 7000 or not. If is then after adding point call:

```
chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, new_max_value);
```

Comment: This looks right on the money, I can add the setExtremes at the end of the function that updates the chart, so its perfect, I wasn't aware you could put equations in the max setting like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what might better suit your needs is a [`plotLines`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines) element. This will let the chart auto-size and still give a representation of what is within spec.

Comment: That was my first thought, but it went against the minimalistic style of the page, and made the page (Or that particular graph) look out of place. But this will always be an option. Strange that they never had a minCeiling option or something, would be good.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `minRange`... set the [minRange option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis--minRange) on your axis and it will always show at least that many values.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/J2f47/5/) is your jsfiddle with minRange.